# LibcOverlayShims.h compile failure

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

When attempting to compile my app, I’m getting an error from the SDK itself:

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "LibcOverlayShims.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/swift/shims/LibcOverlayShims.h:66:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
  return errno;
         ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "LibcOverlayShims.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/swift/shims/LibcOverlayShims.h:70:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'
  errno = value;
  ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftOverlayShims'
```

It almost seems like errno.h isn’t included, but I can see that it is on line 33 of that file. I’ve tried the usual derived data delete, product clean, reinstall Xcode, reboot. I’ve tried stripping parts out of the app to try to see what’s causing it, but haven’t gotten very far.

**Edit**: An archive of the app appears to trigger it. Running in debug mode is perfectly fine, then I archive and it breaks it. Trying to run from debug again fails. Making random changes to the project file, then running a `git reset --hard` then allows debug to work again until I try to archive. It seems like something is wrong with the release settings that then carries over into subsequent debug builds (even with a clean)

Comment: Not maybe a #define DEBUG that is fooling with you?

Comment: My comment crossed your edit ... maybe not a #define given your edit ... maybe your scheme needs editing ...

Comment: Also, remember there is a global C variable called errno and it could be that this is only used in your DEBUG version, so #define DEBUG still remains a suspect in this difficult case ...

Comment: @skaak so interestingly enough, I just edited my scheme and changed the Archive build configuration from release to debug and it built properly. I guess what I don’t understand is why it then takes making random changes and doing a git reset to get it back to where it compiles.

Comment: I also did a whole project search for a `#define DEBUG` and came up with nothing so I don’t think that’s the issue, but never know

Comment: I think random changes just causes the bad file to be recompiled. You need to find the bad file e.g. the one where the funny #define DEBUG is ... it that is it at all. Otherwise the random changes trigger some configuration change. Now the funny thing is that a switch from one scheme to another should trigger a full recompile, so it remains a mystery ... once you find the bug we'll understand it though ... no use trying to understand it now.

Comment: Again crossed ... see if you have any #define in your project? Or rather, check for any #ifdef statements

Comment: ... and errno in C is defined in errno.h so search for files where that header is included

Comment: So I tried going through and manually making all of the release attributes in the build settings equivalent to their debug counterparts and that didn’t help. There’s no manual defines and no ifdefs in here, it’s a relatively simple swift project (1 Swift PM library, 1 Cocoapods library, and 1 internal custom static swift library). There’s also no includes of errno.h (that file from my post seems to be part of Xcode)

Comment: This is becoming chat .... he he he he ... anyhow, maybe next comment we move ... what arch are you compiling for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223054/discussion-between-alex-and-skaak).

Comment: PS ... according to this https://forum.theodinproject.com/t/errno-h-missing-on-macos-when-installing-packages/15960/6 macos 10.14.3 seems to have this issue.

Comment: maybe check if `#import "LibcOverlayShims.h"` should be exchanged with `#include "LibcOverlayShims.h"`

Comment: Also check if maybe you ran out of HDD space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out months later. Our software ships with this folder `/usr/local/opt/company_name` that contains a few libraries, software packages, etc. Our Swift code links with a number of them, so it was easiest to set Xcode to recursively search that directory for both headers and libraries rather than individually specifying them.

For some rather painful reasons, a copy of python is actually shipped in that folder. Well turns out some header file in that python directory was making Xcode very unhappy and triggering that compiler error. I manually specified the libraries we needed to link against and problem solved.